# Newly created edges show on object

Tags: modeling, retopology

What are these line showing up on the object? They appeared after I subdivide two lines to add new edge to the top. I want to make them disappear on the object while still keeping the edge in the topology.[image: Lines showing up on object]

Edit: When I reconnect the vertices and make a face the lines disappear, but now there's an unnecessary face on the inside of the model. Can this not be avoided? I have few experience so my case might just be a bad case of topology

Comment: Hello, maybe overlapping faces? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots I don't think it's overlapping faces, I tried to delete the vertices to see if there's anything under but there wasn't anything. I have uploaded the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=7Ol9k4JB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/7Ol9k4JB/)

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Check the Bisect axis to delete everything on the other side of the modifier.
Check the Clipling box so that you can't move geometry past the mirror modifier

Answer (score 1):

As you see if I select the outer faces, the edges of the inner face are not part of the outer faces, they are overlapping:

[image]

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with this inner face, but in order to have a clean topology, remove the inner face and dissolve these 2 vertices:

[image]

If you need edges on the side, use the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> or loopcut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.